# SQL String Removing Succeeding Characters from a specific character

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've been given a task to display strings that looks like `Foo - Bar`, `Foo-Bar` `Foo        - Bar`, `Foo!.,-Bar`, `Foo...-Bar` and I need to display it as `Foo` only. Meaning I have to remove all the characters after the `-` symbol and all special characters before it. Is there a simple function I can use that can cater all the string instances I have given into the desired output: `Foo`? We use SQL Server 2008 r2.

EDIT: I need to mention that the words Foo and Bar is just a representation of the actual strings so hard coding the string length will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came up with this (Thanks to John Cappelletti for providing sample data, **Please** do it yourself on your future questions):

```
Declare @YourTable table (col varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
 ('Foo - Bar')
,('Foo-Bar')
,('Foo        - Bar')
,('Foo!.,-Bar')
,('Foo...-Bar')
,('aaa Foo - Bar aaa')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  col, 
        LEFT(BeforeDash, LEN(BeforeDash) - PATINDEX('%[a-z]%', REVERSE(BeforeDash))+1)
FROM     
(
    SELECT col, LEFT(col, CHARINDEX('-', col)) As BeforeDash
    FROM @YourTable
) derived
```

Results:

```
col                     Display
Foo - Bar               Foo
Foo-Bar                 Foo
Foo        - Bar        Foo
Foo!.,-Bar              Foo
Foo...-Bar              Foo
aaa Foo - Bar aaa       aaa Foo
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
   declare @String varchar(20)='Foo!.,-Bar'
   select substring(@String,charindex('F', @String),3)
```

Comment: Its true only the text length is 3.

Comment: wait it works only on 3 letter word like foo what if the first word is 3 or more or even 2? like `foot`?

Comment: @super-user my  2nd answer will give result and first answer will give if string starts with 'foo'

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @YourTable table (col varchar(50))
Insert into @YourTable values
 ('Foo - Bar')
,('Foo-Bar')
,('Foo        - Bar')
,('Foo!.,-Bar')
,('Foo...-Bar')
,('aaa Foo-Bar aaa')
,('There is no Bar-Foo here')

Declare @Search varchar(50) = 'Foo - Bar'
Select *
      ,Display = case when col like '%'+Replace(@Search,' ','%')+'%' 
                      then Left(@Search,charindex('-',@Search)-1)
                      else col 
                 end
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
col                         Display
Foo - Bar                   Foo 
Foo-Bar                     Foo 
Foo        - Bar            Foo 
Foo!.,-Bar                  Foo 
Foo...-Bar                  Foo 
aaa Foo-Bar aaa             Foo 
There is no Bar-Foo here    There is no Bar-Foo here
```

Answer (score -1):

```
   DECLARE @STRING VARCHAR(2000)
SET @STRING = 'FOO - DEPTH'


SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(@STRING, 0, CHARINDEX('-', @STRING)),'!',''),'.',''),',','')))
```